# Addressing to a LUT with IEEE-754 format

Tags: memory-address, ieee-754, lookup-tables, fixed-point

When a LUT is used is common get the address for it via bitwise operations over the bits of a
number in fixed point. An example:

```
// The LUT has 8 addres: from 0 to 7 with a step of 1.
// The input number, x, is in u4.8 format

// Input number is 1.748 --> Fixed representation is 447: 0001.10111111
address = bits[1:4] + bits[4] // := 2; Returned value: 2

// Input number is 4.69 --> Fixed representation is 1201: 0100.10110001
address = bits[1:4] + bits[4] // := 5; Returned value: 5

// Input number is 7.22 --> Fixed representation is 1848: 0111.00111000
address = bits[1:4] + bits[4] // := 7; Returned value: 7
```

Ok, we suppose now that the LUT has 16 stored values: from 0 to 7.5 with a step of 0.5. An example:

```
// The LUT has 16 addres: from 0 to 7.5 with a step of 0.5.
// The input number, x, is in u4.8 format

// Input number is 1.748 --> Fixed representation is 447: 0001.10111111
address = bits[1:5] + bits[5] // := 3; Returned value: 1.5

// Input number is 4.69 --> Fixed representation is 1201: 0100.10110001
address = bits[1:5] + bits[5] // := 9; Returned value: 4.5

// Input number is 7.22 --> Fixed representation is 1848: 0111.00111000
address = bits[1:5] + bits[5] // := 14; Returned value: 7
```

The example is only to ilustrate that the goal is obtain the adress that corresponds with the nearest value to the input value based on the step. I achieved this in fixed point with a probability matching greater than 99 % in all the tests.

But, the question is: how to implement it in fp32 (IEEE-754)? Because representation in fp32 doesn't have and integer and fractional part, I have no idea how to implement it...

***EDIT: FIRST APPROACH***

As remarked  @njuffa in the commentaries, the way to address a LUT with the IEEE-754 standard is using the MSB's from the mantissa. This bits contains the address and is neccessary get a specific range of bits always less or equal equal to the address length. I have calculated the number of bits necessaries take it into consideration the bits of the exponent. E.g If the LUT has a step of `1/256`, the way that I have resolved the address is:

```
// To normalize the exponent
exponent = exponent - 127;

// msb indicates the number of bits to get from
// from the mantissa. This bits are the MSB. I have
// checked for large LUTS: 2¹⁸ stored values and always
// works well :)
// The step is 1/256: np.log2(step) = 8 --> The number of
// bits in the step!
msb = int(np.log2(step) - exp) 

// And finally, get the bits from the mantissa
address = mantissa[31:msb]
```

Finally, an addition is necessary if rounding to the nearest is required, but if is it use table interpolation rounding to the nearest, is not neccesary.

I have perceived thtat when the input value is close to zero, sometimes the address is incorrect. Always is a difference of one with the reference test.

This way to resolve the address is right only if the step in the lut is a power of 2. For example: if the step of the LUT was `pi/(4*512)` with a range from `0` to `pi/4`, the total values stored in LUT would be 512, but with a step scalated by `pi`, so will be necessary perform a division as far as I know.

This is the test that I have performed to verify that the address is correct.

```
import numpy as np
import struct

# if mode == 0: No nearest rounding for address
# if mode == 1: Nearest rounding for address
MODE = 0
step = 256 # Step size in the LUT 
max_value = 4 # Only for test purposes
LUT = np.arange(0, max_value, 1/step)

# Reference test
def ref_addressing(x):
    if MODE == 0:
        ref_address = (np.floor(x * step)).astype(np.int32)
    elif MODE == 1:
        ref_address = (np.round(x * step)).astype(np.int32)
    return ref_address

# Test
def test_addressing(x):
    j = 0
    test_address = np.zeros(len(x), dtype=np.int32)
    for x_ in x:
        test_address[j] = ieee754_address(x_)
        j = j + 1
    return test_address



# Convert value to IEEE-754 Standard
def float_to_bin(num):
    bits, = struct.unpack('!I', struct.pack('!f', num))
    return "{:032b}".format(bits)

# Resolves the address with the MSB's bits of the mantissa
def ieee754_address(x):
    ieee754 = float_to_bin(x) # Get the number in IEEE754 Standard
    exp = 127 - int(ieee754[1:9], 2) # Calculte the exponent
    mnt = ieee754[9::] # Get the mantissa
    
    # How many bits are needed for succesfull addresing?
    # np.log2(step): Maximun number of bits in the step size
    # Obviously, these values are fixed in the hardware 
    # implementation. Only for testing.
    msb = int(np.log2(step) - exp)
    
    # Get the address. Don't forget the hidden bit!
    address = int('1'+mnt[0:msb], 2)
    
    # If rounding to the nearest, MODE == 1
    if MODE == 1:
        # int(mnt[msb], 2) --> Rounding bit
        address = address + int(mnt[msb], 2)
    
    # Negatives address if exp > int(np.log2(step)
    if exp > int(np.log2(step):
        address = 0
    return address

# Uniform random values to check all the range
r = np.random.uniform(0.0, max_value, 65536)

# Perform the tests
ref_address = ref_addressing(r)
test_address = test_addressing(r)

# Statistics and report
diffs = ref_address - test_address
errors = len(np.where(diffs != 0)[0])
p = (1 - (errors / len(r))) * 100

print("-----------------------------------")
print("Total test's samples : %i " % (len(r)))
print("-----------------------------------")
print("Equal addrressing    : %r " % (np.array_equal(ref_address, test_address)))
print("Errors               : %i " % errors)
print("Probability matching : %0.3f %% " % p)
print("-----------------------------------")
```

And the sample of an one test (shows False when one or more address are not right):

```
-----------------------------------
Total test's samples : 65536 
-----------------------------------
Equal addrressing    : False 
Errors               : 2 
Probability matching : 99.997 % 
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: LUTs in floating-point arithmetic are typically addressed using some leading bits of the significand (mantissa), occasionally including the least significant bit of the exponent. In other words, the LUT implements the core approximation for reduced argument.

Comment: Hi @njuffa One question: I have thought that the best way to save hardware resources is performing the calculus in fixed point, but my input is in floating point, so the LUT is addressed via floating point and return a fixed point value, later performing the interpolation through it  and finally the fixed point result is converted to the IEEE-754. In this way Is not neccessary the logic to convert from IEEE-754 to fixed point. Is the first time that I make something like that. Is normal doing in this way? Also, storing the values in fixed point I need only 20 bits for value. 

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand your description correctly, yes, this is how it is typically done. There are various published articles available on hardware implementations for low-precision floating-point, e.g. S.F. Oberman and M.Y. Siu, "A high-performance area-efficient multifunction interpolator". In *17th IEEE Symposium on Computer Arithmetic*, June 2005, pp. 272-279.